# How to install keras-bert? (PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels)

Tags: python, r, keras, conda

I'm trying to install `keras-bert` as explained here: [BERT from R](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-09-30-bert-r/). This tutorial shows how to load and train the BERT model from `R`, using `Keras`.

But when, in Anaconda prompt (Windows), I run:

```
conda install keras-bert
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - keras-bert

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I also navigate to https://anaconda.org, searching for `keras-bert`, but there were no items found for this search.

I also tried with:

```
python3 -m pip install keras-bert
```

and I obtain no output:

```
(base) C:\Users\Standard>python3 -m pip install keras-bert

(base) C:\Users\Standard>
```

but when I went to check whether keras-bert was installed or not, with R command

```
reticulate::py_module_available('keras_bert')
```

I obtained:

```
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Install from YAML in new env

Since this requires mixing PyPI packages with Conda, [the best practice recommendation for this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env) is to create a dedicated environment using a YAML file. You may need additional version constraints in here to achieve a setup that works with the tutorial, but this YAML is sufficient for me to do the first steps:

**bert_env.yaml**

```yaml
name: bert_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - keras
  - pip
  - pip:
    - keras-bert
```

Running

```shell
conda env create -f bert_env.yaml
```

creates the env named **bert_env**.

From an R session, I can then run

```r
> reticulate::use_condaenv("bert_env", required=TRUE)

> reticulate::py_config()
# python:         /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/bert_env/bin/python
# libpython:      /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/bert_env/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
# pythonhome:     /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/bert_env:/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/bert_env
# version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 23:06:31)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
# numpy:          /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/bert_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
# numpy_version:  1.18.5

> reticulate::py_module_available("keras_bert")
# [1] TRUE

> tensorflow::tf_config()
# TensorFlow v2.0.0 ()
# Python v3.6 (~/miniconda3/envs/bert_env/bin/python)
```

This was all run on an **osx-64** platform, so **win-64** will likely differ in the versions it pulls down. In the end, though, it should mainly be a matter of [tweaking the YAML](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually).