# How should I install keras-bert to use properly on R side?

Tags: python, keras, package, conda, reticulate

I am trying to install keras-bert as explained [here](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2019-09-30-bert-r/). Although it is successfully installed on the environment as, I cannot see keras-bert inside the R side.

```
(bert_env) C:\Users\xxxxx\Dropbox\Rcode\ProjectBERT>pip list
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- ---------
certifi                          2022.6.15
keras                            2.6.0
keras-bert                       0.89.0
keras-embed-sim                  0.10.0
keras-layer-normalization        0.16.0
keras-multi-head                 0.29.0
keras-pos-embd                   0.13.0
keras-position-wise-feed-forward 0.8.0
keras-self-attention             0.51.0
keras-transformer                0.40.0
mkl-fft                          1.3.1
mkl-random                       1.2.2
mkl-service                      2.4.0
numpy                            1.23.1
pip                              22.1.2
setuptools                       61.2.0
six                              1.16.0
wheel                            0.37.1
wincertstore                     0.2
```

Another proof which shows keras-bert is successfully install on the current environment (`bert_env`):

```
(bert_env) C:\Users\xxxxx\Dropbox\Rcode\ProjectBERT>pip install keras-bert
Requirement already satisfied: keras-bert in c:\anaconda3\envs\bert_env\lib\site-packages (0.89.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-transformer==0.40.0 in c:\anaconda3\envs\bert_env\lib\site-packages (from keras-bert) (0.40.0)
```

However, I cannot properly call the package on the R side which says:

```
> reticulate::conda_list()
      name                                   python
1     base                 C:\\Anaconda3/python.exe
2 bert_env C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bert_env/python.exe
3     py27     C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py27/python.exe
> reticulate::use_condaenv("bert_env", required=TRUE)
> reticulate::py_config()
C:\ANACON~2\envs\bert_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
python:         C:/Anaconda3/envs/bert_env/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Anaconda3/envs/bert_env/python310.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Anaconda3/envs/bert_env
version:        3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 30 2022, 08:38:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Anaconda3/envs/bert_env/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.23.1
```

I have almost tried everything which offered as solution such as:

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

Then I have created a fully clean new environment in order to reinstall keras-bert on there. Also looked scipy and numpy package conflicts which is mentioned on their github side. No success at all!

Of course, once I check availability, it returns false!

```
reticulate::py_module_available('keras_bert')
[1] FALSE
```

I am aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532838/how-to-install-keras-bert-packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-no) and applied exactly same patterns with YAML. No improvements as well. Any suggestions to properly install keras-bert or how should I approach the issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try declaring the environment at the start of the R session? [I've had problems in the past](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/292#issuecomment-483339105) with other libraries preventing the declared reticulate environment from being respected. That is, when R starts, do `reticulate::use_condaenv("bert_env", required=TRUE)` absolutely first.

Comment: @merv I am already doing it exactly you pointed it out. In order to give more information about my current situation, I just organized the question in the above.

Comment: @merv In addition, I have used reticulate::use_python instead of reticulate::use_condaenv by giving the full path, it does not help for the solution as well. I really do not know how I should approach the issue :(

Comment: Okay - I've been able to recreate issue on [a GitHub Windows runner.](https://github.com/mfansler/conda-envs-testing/runs/7792222468?check_suite_focus=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days search, I found a way to set the reticulate path properly. This issue solves the main issue as well. **.Renviron file** is a user-controllable file that can be used to create environment variables. Hence, the .Renviron file can be used to store the information which can be accessed from all R projects in your computer.

**First of all**, you need to find the location of your `.Renviron` file. In order to find the path of your `.Renviron` file, you can type this on RStudio console:

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

In my case, it returns:

```
* Modify 'C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/.Renviron'
* Restart R for changes to take effect
```

Then, you might either navigate the location of `.Renviron` file manually. (Note: It was empty once I opened it in my scenario.) Then paste the full path of `python.exe` inside to the file as:

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="YourEnvironmentPath/python.exe"
```

**Tip**: If you are not sure about your full python path, you can get it as:

```
reticulate::conda_python("keras_bert")
```

Please do not forget to type your environment name instead of my environment nam > `keras_bert`).
Then I got:

```
[1] "C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\keras_bert/python.exe"
```

In my case, I pasted:

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON="C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\keras_bert/python.exe"
```

Or (on Windows), you can click on start and open *Windows Powershell*. Then copy this code into powershell to handle same thing:

```
Add-Content C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents/.Renviron 'RETICULATE_PYTHON="C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\keras_bert/python.exe"'
```

In order to see updates, you must close and reopen RStudio to have a clean RStudio session. Now, run the following line to check whether everything is fine or not:

```
Sys.getenv('RETICULATE_PYTHON')
```

or:

```
reticulate::py_config()
```

In my case, it returns:

```
[1] "C:/Anaconda3/envs/keras_bert/python.exe"
```

or:

```
python: C:/Anaconda3/envs/keras_bert/python.exe
libpython: C:/Anaconda3/envs/keras_bert/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Anaconda3/envs/keras_bert
version:        3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 05:59:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Anaconda3/envs/keras_bert/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.23.2

NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON
```

Briefly, with this solution, you do not need to care about whether you declare the environment at the start of the R session or any other messy scenarios.