# Simple BERT implementation on R side

Tags: r, tensorflow, bert-language-model, transformer-model, reticulate

I would like to implement a simple text classification using BERT model on **R** side. On my local side, I have no progress because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73323839/how-should-i-install-keras-bert-to-use-properly-on-r-side). Therefore, I moved to kaggle platform. Also, I have started to replicate [this kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/code/pehahn/basic-bert-with-r/). However, I could not succeed to call `transformer$TFBertModel` because this line throws me the below error. As you might guess that there are few tutorials BERT on R side, so I am also appreciated for any simple BERT text classification tutorial based on R (over kaggle).

```
ERROR
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent): RuntimeError: Failed to import transformer...
```

as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(LiblineaR)
library(tidymodels)
library(rsample)

reticulate::py_install('transformers', pip = TRUE)

transformer = reticulate::import('transformers')
tf = reticulate::import('tensorflow')
builtins <- import_builtins()

tokenizer <- transformer$AutoTokenizer$from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

BERT = transformer$TFBertModel$from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

print("completed...")
```

Comment: I didn't get the error. I used RStudio. Are all your packages up to date?

Comment: As I explained throughout the question, it is on kaggle kernel not on RStudio.

Comment: Yes, So it is not a possibility for you to use Rstudio?

Comment: This is another issue which I have posted in another stackoverflow question. I have also linked the current post to the one I am talking about. You might see the link at the beginning of the question ?